# Setting tracking cookie on client side vs server side?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

We want to set tracking cookie to check how many users we are getting through various marketing campaigns. On each campaign URL of our website, we add following query string parameters:- utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign.

Sample URL:- https://example.com/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=jan

Anytime, we get request from any URL on our server, we check:

1. If url has utm_* parameters, we save those in the cookie.
2. If there's no such utm_* parameters in the url and If referer host is our website i.e. https://example.com/, we save that in cookie for 6 months.
3. If there's no such utm_* parameters in the url and referer is one of search engine, we save search engine name in cookie.

and we have few more similar conditions.

Should we write this logic on server side (C#) OR Client side(javascript)?

Comment: Either.
- - - - -

Comment: Is this for Google Analytics?

Comment: this is for analytics.. not only for GA.. we save this cookie on each order/transaction/led to tag which lead came from which campaign/medium/source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can do it on either end; but in reality, you might have slightly better luck with a server side approach as it will be harder for browsers to get around (either they accept cookies or not). Things like noscript and adblockers could interfere with a client side implementation.

Additionally, if you do things server side, you could store that information along with a thumb print of the browser in a database and compare against that for future visits. That would work even if cookies are being blocked/cleared.

Comment: if browser doesn't accept cookie, even if we set it from server side, it would be problematic, right? as they still won't allow cookies

Comment: correction:- if browser doesn't accept cookie, even if we set it from server side, it would be problematic, right? as when cookie would come from server to browser, the browser still won't allow cookies. So, server won't get that cookie information in the next request